# Which type should I use for a pointer ?  ptrdiff_t or void*?

Tags: c, pointers, c89

Which line is the correct (best) way for defining a pointer?

```
typedef ptrdiff_t pointer; // pointers are ptrdiff_t.

          -- or --

typedef void* pointer; // pointers are void*.


pointer ptr = malloc(1024);
```

Comment: `void *ptr = malloc(1024);` :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pointers in C are of type `T*` where `T` is the type pointed to; `void*` is the generic pointer type. Usually, you let C implicitly convert `void*` to something useful, e.g.

```
char *buffer = malloc(1024);
```

`ptrdiff_t` is the type returned by the subtraction of two pointers, e.g.

```
ptrdiff_t d = write_ptr - buffer;
// now you know the write_ptr is d bytes beyond the start of the buffer
```

`ptrdiff_t` is an integral type, not a pointer type; you cannot use the indirection operator `*` on it. (Nor can you meaningfully use it on a `void*`, by the way.)

Had you wanted to store a pointer in an integer type, `uintptr_t` would have been appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

The *best* way of declaring a pointer is

```
T *ptr;
```

where `T` is the base type being pointed to -- `int`, `char`, `struct foo`, whatever.  `malloc` returns a `void *`, which is implicitly converted to the target pointer type, so all of the following are equally valid:

```
char *str = malloc(512);                       // allocates space for 512 chars
int *arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * 512);          // allocates space for 512 ints
struct foo *farr = malloc(sizeof *farr * 512); // allocates space for 512 struct foos
int (*arr2)[10] = malloc (sizeof *arr2 * 512); // allocates space for 512x10 ints
```

etc., etc., etc.

There is no *single* pointer data type in C; there are multiple "pointer to `T`" data types.  Pointer arithmetic depends on the base type; `str + 1` will yield a different value from `arr + 1`, which will yield a different value from `farr + 1`, etc.  `void *` is the "generic" pointer type, but you don't *want* to use generic pointers for everything.

Do not hide pointer types behind typedefs, *unless* the pointer type is meant to be opaque and never dereferenced, and even then it's usually a bad idea.